# AWS Glue Job migration from dynamoDb to dynamoDB, but it is copying decimal number only and whole number copying as null values

Tags: pyspark, amazon-dynamodb, aws-glue

We are migration data from one dynamoDb to other dynamoDB using AWS Glue job, But when we run the job it copied column A of dataType double( eg , value - 11,12, 13.5, 16.8 ) from source table to destination table , it is coping column A data ( null, null, 13.5, 16.8) which is in decimal and whole number is copied as null value.

```
 Source Table : 

 item1 - {
      "amount": {
      "N": "34.85"
    }

  item2 - {
      "amount": {
      "N": "28.85"
    }

 item3 - {
      "amount": {
      "N": "14"
    }
}

Destination Table : 
 { item1 - {
      "amount": {
      "N": "34.85"
    }

  item2 - {
      "amount": {
      "N": "28.85"
    }

 item3 - {
      "amount": {
      "Null": Null
    }
}

 Expected Destination Table : 

 {item1 - {
      "amount": {
      "N": "34.85"
    }

  item2 - {
      "amount": {
      "N": "28.85"
    }

 item3 - {
      "amount": {
      "N": "14"
    }
}

Custom column Transformation in glue job  :

 frame=AWSGlueDataCatalog_node16,
    mappings=[
        ("amount", "double", "amount", "double")
       
    ],
    transformation_ctx="ChangeSchemaApplyMapping_node12"
```

Any quick help will be much appreciated !!!
-Thanks in Advance